# Can't afford so I pirate

Tags: piracy

I can't afford the colossal prices of Games, Movies or Books. The thing is if I could afford them I would have surely bought them. So if piracy wasn't an option I wouldn't have purchased these anyways. That way I'm not doing any harm to the creators of such content, I don't see why would it be wrong. And there are these online courses which I can't afford, and I can't find any free ones, but they are available on torrent, so knowledge is right there to be reached but is it permissible that way?

I'm from Pakistan ( no ban on piracy as much as I know)
I'm 17 years old.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] for further information. Note that playing games is hardly allowed in Islam nor is it among the necessary things in life, so stealing in such a case would certainly be considered as not allowed. As shari'a may turn a blind eye in case of need or necessity, but not in case of comfort.

Comment: Technically you are doing harm to the creators - they are not getting what they should be getting for payment for the effort they have made into creating software, books, movies etc... so yes, it is harm to them absolutely!

Comment: Your assumption of "That way I'm not doing any harm to the creators of such content" is wrong. You are doing harm to them, by using their product, without paying them the price they ask for it. It doesn't make a difference if you can afford it or not. If it is not distributed/shared freely by its owner/publisher, you can't use it without paying its price. If you ever create something digital and put it on sale you will better understand why it is wrong. Sometimes publishers may give freely if you kindly ask. Or, if you write a blog post about their product, they may give you a review copy.

Answer (score 1):

Since the owner of these tutorials has put a price for it's videos or other stuffs in it's official webiste or webpage then it is prohibited to access in pirate sites to take the online courses. Because it is considered stealing something. But to be more sure for that and to clearify your mind you can write an email to the owner of the video that a pirate site is offering your courses for free. In that way he or she will give you a clear information if this thing is known to them or not. So  their answer crucial in the verdict if it is allowed or not. But anyway if you do this thing you are part of the ayat:

> وتعاونوا على البر والتقوى ولا تعاونوا على الإثم والعدوان.
>   And cooperate in righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in sin and aggression.

You cooperated in righteousness, and inshaaAllah you will be rewarded for that.
And الله اعلم. God knows best.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about our site and the SE model.